# How to make partial show some code only for specific collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, partial-views

I'm using the same partial two times within a view for different collections. This works:

```
<%= render partial: 'organizations/organization', collection: @organizations %>
<%= render partial: 'organizations/organization', collection: @members %>
```

But part of the partial I would only like to be displayed for the `@members` collection. Is there some syntax that makes this possible? So something that basically achieves:

```
# Inside parial:
<% if collection: @members %>
  <td><%= organization.fish %></td>
<% end %>
```

Background: In the `users controller` I have (`@members` and `organizations` may partially overlap, so in the partial I don't think the can differentiate on basis of what is behind the `=`; instead if possible it is necessary to differentiate in the partial on basis of which collection (before the `=` got passed to the partial):

```
def show
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @members = @user.organizations.where('member = ?', true)
  @organizations = @user.organizations.where('moderator = ?', true)
  ...
end
```

Or can I perhaps when rendering the partial pass on a key, and then in the partial that if that key is `true` it only then displays a piece of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking type on each iteration of your loop, I would advise you to utilize "duck typing" and add a method on your model that determines what type of instance it is:

**Adjusting after getting more information from the question**

```
class Organization

  def organization_type
     # your logic to set or determine whether it is an organization or a member
     return "member" if member?
     return "moderator" if moderator?
     "organization"
  end

end
```

Then in your partial:

```
<% if organization.organization_type == "member" %>
  <td><%= organization.fish %></td>
<% end %>
```

It is just a rough idea of how it can be done. In this case, you can even pass a mixed collection of objects to your partial, and if each of the models defines organization_type in it, it will be displayed properly.

**After you comments**

```
 <%= render partial: 'organizations/organization', collection: @members, member_flag: true %>
```

In your partial:

```
<% if local_assigns[:member_flag] && member_flag %>
  <td><%= organization.fish %></td>
<% end %>
```

**The third try**

```
# Per @Nick's correction in his comment about locals.

<%= render partial: 'organizations/organization', collection: @organizations, locals: { member_flag: false } %>
<%= render partial: 'organizations/organization', collection: @members, locals: { member_flag: true } %>

<% if local_assigns[:member_flag] && member_flag %>
  <td><%= organization.fish %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The problem would then still be the same in that the type does not per se differentiate between the two collections. They overlap.

Comment: @Nick: If above is not what you want, then I updated the answer to pass an _optional_ variable member_flag for such cases.

Comment: @Nick: I doubt you can do without additional parameter, considering the fact that you do not rely on Organization's organization_type method to determine whether some information should be displayed or not.

Comment: Thanks @Gen, I tried it, but since it renders both collections on the same page it sees member_flag = true and displays the code for both collections, even though only for one collection the member_flag gets passed on. Perhaps there's no choice and one just has to use two partials in such a use case...

Comment: @Nick: then just specify the member_flag for both. I updated the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately that makes no difference. I think the browser can only have one value in memory for member_flag for one and the same view.

Comment: @Nick: but rendering happens on the server, and browser has noting to do with it. Can you double check? It should work. I have used similar things a lot.

Comment: Sorry, it really doesn't work, also the order of true false (whether the first partial rendering has true and the other false or vice versa) doesn't matter.

Comment: I found the cause it initially didn't work. I needed to set the flag using: `locals: { member_flag: true }` instead of just `member_flag: true`. Then it does work.

Comment: @Nick: You are right in both cases. It was overwritten in my first edition, and you found the right way to fix it. I will update my answer with your corrections and your reference.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that @members is a collection of `Member`. You can do it like

```
<% if organization.member %>
  <td><%= organization.fish %></td>
<% end%>
```

Comment: Thanks, `members` is a collection from `Organization`. It's defined in the users controller and consists of the organizations of which that user is a member. I guess then this setup doesn't work?

Comment: How do you differentiate @organizations from @members?

Comment: I've added the part where I define the variables to the OP.

Comment: Thanks, the problem with that would be that `@members` and `@organizations` partially overlap. Therefore, we can't differentiate in the partial on basis of what defines `@members` and `@organizations`. I think it needs to be defined on basis of whether `@members` or `@organizations` is defined as the collection.